# Effective way to flatten a list resulting from a LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, list, linq, flatten

I am trying to flatten the result of my query with this code:

```
Dim listHmisNum = (From plc In plctags
                   Where plc.xType.ToUpper.Contains("HMINUM")).ToList

Dim listHmisNums = (From hmisnum In listHmisNum
                   Select (From plc In plctags
                           Where plc.xName.Contains(hmisnum.xName) And
                           plc.xValue <> "{...}")).ToList

Dim flattenList = (From list In listHmisNums
                               From item In list
                               Select item).ToList
```

The variable listHmisNums has the type 
`System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of MyType))`

I am able to flatten it, but my issue is that it takes forever to flatten it when my list `listHmisNums`  get bigger.

I was wondering if you had more effective way of flattening it?

I might also be going the wrong the way I query my data.

Comment: You probably ought to look at the `SelectMany` method.

Comment: I believed that a query like this
`Dim flattenList = (From list In listHmisNums
                               From item In list
                               Select item).ToList`
Was the LINQ equivalent to SelectMany?

[Link to a blog talking about this](https://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/select-many-operator-part-1)

Comment: I look at that line of code and I'm not sure what it will do, or if it even compiles. Just use `SelectMany`

Answer (score 1):

If you switch from going over the `plctags` list for each `listHmisNum` element, to the opposite, does performance improve?

```
Dim listHmisNum = (From plc In plctags
                   Where plc.xType.ToUpper.Contains("HMINUM")
                   Select plc.xName).ToList

Dim flattenList = (From plc In plctags
                   Where listHmisNum.Any(Function (n) plc.xName.Contains(n)) And plc.xValue <> "{...}"
                   Select plc).ToList
```

Consider your original code:

```
Dim listHmisNums = (From hmisnum In listHmisNum
                   Select (From plc In plctags
                           Where plc.xName.Contains(hmisnum.xName) And
                           plc.xValue <> "{...}")).ToList
```

If you consider the type of `listHmisNums`, you will see it is a `List<IEnumerable<Tplctags>>`. The `ToList` instantiates the outer `From`...`Select` but leaves the inner query [deferred](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/deferred-execution-vs-immediate-execution-in-linq/) i.e. to be executed when the results are needed. Each deferred query scans the elements of `plctags` and pulls out the matching ones.

```
Dim flattenList = (From list In listHmisNums
                               From item In list
                               Select item).ToList
```

Now `flattenList` is of type `List<Tplctags>` and `list` is of type `IEnumerable<Tplctags>` and is deferred. When this query is executed, the results are processed for every deferred query in the `listHmisNums` query.  So if there are 4000 elements in `listHmisNum` then evaluating the 4000 deferred queries means scanning all the elements of `plctags` 4000 times to retrieve the `40` matching elements.

By rewriting the query to scan `plctags` once, and find the first match (`Any`)in `listHmisNums`, which has already been instantiated using `ToList`, we greatly reduce the number of nested loop processing needed.

Comment: I used

`Dim flattenList = (From plc In plctags.AsParallel
                               Where listHmisNum.Any(Function(n) plc.xName.Contains(n)) And plc.xValue <> "{...}"
                               Select plc).ToList`

and it went down to never actually finishing to be under 4 minutes which is a big improvement so thank you very much.


Also, as you can see I added .AsParallel. This is making it run under 4 minutes.

**I am still confused why a list of 4000 elements where each of them contains 20 elements take so much time to process.**

Comment: @GuillaumeCollin I added an explanation. Can you say how many elements are in `plctags`, `listHmisNum`, and each member of `listHmisNums`?